# Nginx : Sub-domain fails while primary domain, which falls back to sub-domain, succeeds

Tags: nginx, subdomain

### Introduction :

I have a machine on my local network, running NginX. It won't let me access my sub-domain directly, instead it directs me to the NginX index page. If I access the primary domain I get redirected to the sub-domain which loads the proxied site correctly.

That is accessing `git.lini.lan` will simply fail and load the NginX index page.

[image: NginX fails to load proxied site given sub-domain]

What I am expecting to happen is that `git.lini.lan` will load the proxied site, GitlabHQ.

[image: NginX proxies site correctly given sub-domain]

Accessing the primary domain `lini.lan` falls back to the only configured site/virtual host, `git.lini.lan`, which loads the proxied site, GitlabHQ, as expected.

[image: NginX redirects primary domain to sub-domain and loads the proxied site]

So I can access the proxied site via an indirect request to the primary domain but I can not access it by directly specifying the subdomain.

### Observations :

My understanding is that accessing `lini.lan` redirects to the "default" virtual host. Since I have not set one using the directive `listen ... default_server;` NginX defaults to the first virtual host, which serves `git.lini.lan`. When one accesses `git.lini.lan` directly, however, NginX falls back onto the index page for no apparent reason.

### Homework :

For comparison I have another machine that works as expected, but that machine is online, has it's own DNS records setup and uses SSL so there is not quite a 1 to 1 comparison between the NginX configurations on the two machines. For example, it might be possible that the DNS record goes some way to fix anything wierd things that NginX might be doing. I have diff'd the configuration files between the two machines and the two configurations are really equivalent, after ignoring the SSL stuff.

I have also gone through my log files but there is nothing that seems to be out of place.

### Theory :

As I have been fiddling with this this afternoon, here is what I have learnt. My "default" virtual host/server configuration must be read correctly otherwise I could not have access to GitlabHQ. That is the proxy succeeds and loads as expected. It is the NginX routing that seems to be a little incorrect.

### Information :

My configuration for the machine that is being wierd is below. This is my output for `nginx -T`.

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user nginx nginx;
worker_processes 1;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error_log info;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
        use epoll;
}

http {
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        log_format main
                '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
                '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
                '"$gzip_ratio"';

        client_header_timeout 10m;
        client_body_timeout 10m;
        send_timeout 10m;

        connection_pool_size 256;
        client_header_buffer_size 1k;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 2k;
        request_pool_size 4k;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1100;
        gzip_buffers 4 8k;
        gzip_types text/plain;

        output_buffers 1 32k;
        postpone_output 1460;

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;

        keepalive_timeout 75 20;

        ignore_invalid_headers on;

        index index.html;

        include /etc/nginx/sites/*.conf;

}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    ...
    List of MIME Types
    ...
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites/gitlab.conf:

upstream git.lini.lan {
  server unix:/opt/gitlabhq-8.15/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  server_name git.lini.lan;

  root /opt/gitlab-8.15/public;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
  }

  location @gitlab {
    proxy_read_timeout 300;    # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_connect_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass http://git.lini.lan;
  }
}
```

### Literature:

I have gone through [server names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) and [request processing](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html). I have also reviewed some of the other SO questions that seemed relevant but none seemed to cover my scenario.

### Problem:

My problem is that when I enter the sub-domain in my browser, I get the NginX index page not the proxied site at the sub-domain i.e. `git.lini.lan` redirects to the NginX **index** page and not to **GitlabHQ**'s interface. I'm not sure why this is happening ?

Perhaps one might have encountered this and could shed some light ? Alternatively is there a means of logging everything that NginX does so that I might have more information to scrounge through.

Comment: This isn't a failover or a redirect, you're proxying a server. What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: Sorry the question was a bit indirect. I just included a more formal query. Hopefully it's more clearer now...

Comment: What subdomain? This is a little unclear with all the fake domains that aren't used consistently throughout your post. Please edit your question.

Comment: I suggest you contact your IT support provider about this. The questions you're asking and terms you're using suggest you don't really understand your current setup.

Comment: @Tim I've just gone through it all one more time, cleaned up some of the more ambiguous stuff. Included some diagrams of the problem and organized it into sensible sounding sections. I'm more familiar with Apache then I am NginX so the terms might be a little muddled. I don' have a techie I can call, I'm it as it were.

Comment: To Tim and Michael Hampton I know one should not really post thanks on here but correcting the jargon helped to eventually resolve the problem. Taking the step back allowed me to see the problem lay at the router and not the server and I'd like to show my appreciation for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my DHCP server which manages my network was misconfigured. The machines on the network were as follows :

```
...
192.168.1.10 devbox.lan The machine I was on
192.168.1.11 lini.lan   The target server
...
```

The hostname record on the DNS server was configured as follows :

```
...
192.168.1.10 git.lini.lan
...
```

Where `git.lini.lan` incorrectly pointed back to `192.168.1.10`, my devbox, and not to `192.168.1.11`, the Gitlab Server.

So requests to `lini.lan` would proceed as shown in the original question. They reached the correct box, NginX would default the to first virtual host and serve the gitlab main page. Requests to the machine name itself, `lini`, would also work as the DHCP server would map these to `lini.lan`.

Requests to `git.lini.lan`, however, would incorrectly redirect back to my machine, where the local server does not recognize the URL and serves the default index page.

### Note :

Originally I struck upon this problem while performing the gitlab self check, `sudo -u git bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info --trace RAILS ENV=production`, and kept getting the message *"Check GitLab API access: FAILED: Failed to connect to internal API"*. The self check uses the URL `git.lini.lan` in it's tests causing all the requests to be directed to the development box rather then the gitlab server, as described above.